# Why MKCircleRenderer is drawing a circle cropped as an square?

Tags: ios, mapkit

I'm using a MKCircleRenderer which is going to be repainted when the size of the circle is changed, but when the circle resizes, this happens...

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9m1ge.jpg)
Instead of a circle, it ends drawing a square when it doesn't have space

this is the method I'm using

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx{

MKMapPoint mpoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate([[self overlay] coordinate]);
CGFloat radiusAtLatitude = (_mapRadius)*MKMapPointsPerMeterAtLatitude([[self overlay] coordinate].latitude);
MKMapRect circleRect = MKMapRectMake(mpoint.x, mpoint.y, radiusAtLatitude,radiusAtLatitude);
CGRect overlayRect = [self rectForMapRect:circleRect];

UIGraphicsPushContext(ctx);
CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, self.fillColor.CGColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [self.fillColor colorWithAlphaComponent:_circleAlpha].CGColor);
CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, _border);
CGContextSetShouldAntialias(ctx, YES);

CGContextAddArc(ctx, overlayRect.origin.x, overlayRect.origin.y, radiusAtLatitude, 0, 2 * M_PI, true);
CGContextDrawPath(ctx, kCGPathFillStroke);


UIGraphicsPopContext();
}
```

Any clue would help me a lot, thanks in advance!

Comment: What am I looking for in the screenshot? I see only circles.

Comment: Sorry draco (just focus on the big circle), which somehow is being cropped (that's my issue), the circle appears nice at the begining when it is small, but if I resize it to make it bigger, it starts cropping like that.

Comment: Oh, I see now.  Somehow my brain registered that as like, the boundary of a city or something.